# Testng.xml is missing testng run option

Tags: xml, eclipse, testng

[image]

hi everyone in my Eclipse i have installed Testng but for some xml the testng option is not being shown as you can see in the picture.. So please help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. it got fixed when I removed extra lines and spaces in below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
```

Answer (score 0):

The TestNG plug-in doesn't seem to be installed, you can verify by going in the "About Eclipse" dialog and then "Installation details".

Comment: hi Cedric i have installed TestNG still im not getting it for that testng.xml only because there are other xml where im using it but for this one only it not coming

Answer (score 0):

Copy the content of testng-failed.xml or any working xml to testng.xml and update necessary lines with your info and try. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

You must have been using the wrong tag conventions that's why it's not coming 
    Create a new file with name testng.xml in the project and copy paste the below code in your testng.xml file and change the packagename.class_name according to your package. You must get that option. if still you don't get just let me know

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="SuiteA"  > 
<!-- suite name="Suite Name" AND Please remember all the tag names should be lowered case otherwise the sytem will throw an error --> 


             <test name="TestA1" allow-return-values="true">
                     <classes>
                       <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                             <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteA.TestCaseA1" />
                     </classes>
             </test>

             <test name="TestA2" allow-return-values="true">
                     <classes>
                       <!-- packagename.Testcase class name  -->
                             <class name ="com.qtpselenium.suiteA.TestCaseA1" />
                     </classes>
             </test>



</suite>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of right clicking on testing.xml try to right click on agency_test and then try to run it.

Comment: hai User2107316 Thanks for the reply .. actually i need to run that particular test case only, for that i need the testng.xml to run in testng configu.. your idea will not work as it will execute the entire test code under that folder all i need is to run that ContactTest.jar with this testng.xml plz suggest answer for that and i will surelly vote for you :-D .. Thanks again ..

Comment: hey SOFT you didnt mention clearly it in your question so you dont have to vote down for me.ok so make it clear lol.